# Ghost boot disk on a pen drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb-flash-drive, norton-ghost

I am in process of ghosting several windows 7 machines. I have disk but no pc comes with floppy drives. So I need an external so I was hoping to create a bootable pen drive with ghost. I have the drive bootable but now need Ghost on it.

Comment: Damn good question, I just realized how important this is going to be for myself (I just built a new computer, and am forcing myself to abandon CDs/DVDs).  I don't know if this will work or not, but you need the Win7 ISO/disk.  Put the Ghost Recovery Disk (ISO) onto the USB key, and in the boot folder, execute `BOOTSECT /NT60 X:`, where `X:` is your USB key drive letter.  Although that might only work with newer versions - what version of Ghost are you using?

Comment: The series of boot disks known as Bart and BartPE have options to include Ghost. They were originally meant to be bootable as CD's but there is info about booting from USB. However, current versions of Ghost limit stand alone use like this, so you'll have to use an older version of ghost - that unfortunately has problems with modern disks and partitions. Best to use a current Ghost install CD which allows booting from CD. You can use an external USB CD drive.

Comment: You can use YUMI Multiboot:http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/  and download MS DOS 6.22 http://www.allbootdisks.com/download/iso.html and install it on the usb drive. Once installed, you can then add tools/utilities to the thumb drive to access ghost. Add other ISO boot disks too. I use it with Ghost8... but I prefer my custom WinPE boot disk.

Comment: Today, i would stay away from DOS-based boot environments unless you are 100% certain that you don't need (or you do have DOS-based) drivers for any kind of secondary SATA/SAS controller or RAID configuration you might encounter.

Comment: Are you talking about a DOS version of Ghost or the newer Windows-based Ghost?  The answers will be completely different depending on this.  We used NetBootDisk to create a floppy image for the DOS version, and then some utility from HP to copy the floppy image to a USB key.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a LiveCD or iso with Ghost on it?
If so, you may be able to use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make the pen drive into a bootable copy of the disc.

Answer (score -1):

I know you can make bootable CDs with Ghost these days.  In the past, I used to create bootable CDs, by using the floppy image.